# Conditional dropdown divider?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a dropdown whose menu items I am populating via a list (not hardcoded). I want a divider after the first item in that list. All the documentation on dividers I can find *only* deals with dividers in hardcoded lists. How do I do this?

```
<Dropdown>
    <Dropdown.Toggle size='sm' variant='outline-primary'>{selectedView}</Dropdown.Toggle>
    <Dropdown.Menu>
        {
            viewList.filter( v => v !== selectedView ).map(view => {
                return (
                    <Dropdown.Item value={view} key={view} >{view}</Dropdown.Item>
                    // if the view = "Create New", add divider after it
                );
            })
        }
    </Dropdown.Menu>
</Dropdown>
```

I can't seem to do anything other than html / jsx elements in the map function, and I don't think there's any "hidden" attribute on a Dropdown.Divider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add conditional renderings for your divider component

If you want to have a divider after the first item, you can use the index value

```
<Dropdown>
    <Dropdown.Toggle size='sm' variant='outline-primary'>{selectedView}</Dropdown.Toggle>
    <Dropdown.Menu>
        {
            viewList.filter( v => v !== selectedView ).map((view, index) => {
                return (
                  <>
                    <Dropdown.Item value={view} key={view} >{view}</Dropdown.Item>
                    {index === 0 && <Dropdown.Divider/>}
                 </>
                );
            })
        }
    </Dropdown.Menu>
</Dropdown>
```

If you want to have a divider after the dropdown item "Create New", you can check `view` value directly

```
<Dropdown>
    <Dropdown.Toggle size='sm' variant='outline-primary'>{selectedView}</Dropdown.Toggle>
    <Dropdown.Menu>
        {
            viewList.filter( v => v !== selectedView ).map(view => {
                return (
                  <>
                    <Dropdown.Item value={view} key={view} >{view}</Dropdown.Item>
                    {view === "Create New" && <Dropdown.Divider/>}
                  </>
                );
            })
        }
    </Dropdown.Menu>
</Dropdown>
```

*Side note that `<></>` is [React's fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) to group JSX elements*

Answer (score 0):

you get index variable while using map function, use the index to know if its the first element and render the divider

```
<Dropdown>
    <Dropdown.Toggle size='sm' variant='outline-primary'>{selectedView}</Dropdown.Toggle>
    <Dropdown.Menu>
        {
            viewList.filter( v => v !== selectedView ).map(view => {
                return (
                  <>
                    <Dropdown.Item value={view} key={view} >{view}</Dropdown.Item>
                    // if the view = "Create New", add divider after it
                    { index === 0 && <YourDivider/> }
                 </>
                );
            })
        }
    </Dropdown.Menu>
</Dropdown>
```